# Xcode 7, Obj-C, "Null passed to a callee that requires a non-null argument"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

In Xcode 7, I'm getting this warning:

```
Null passed to a callee that requires a non-null argument
```

.. from this nil initialization of a NSMutableArray...

```
    sectionTitles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:nil];
```

I've found that I should be using `removeAllObjects` instead.

```
    [sectionTitles removeAllObjects];
```

However, this doesn't allow me to evaluate a `sectionTitles.count == 0`. I did try `sectionTitles == nil`, however unless I use `iniWithObjects` I can't add objects later on.

I need to set the array to nil or zero, when I refresh my datasource, when there's no records. I don't seem to be able to use `addObject` to add items unless I've used `initWithObjects`.

Comment: You can only work with an initialized object. Calling count on nil would work, though.

Comment: `if (sectionTitles.count != nil)` causes a warning?

Comment: Either `[sectionTitles removeAllObjects]` or `sectionTitles = [NSMutableArray array]` should work, they are logically the same (though performance could differ).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Why don't you try:

```
sectionTitles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

or any of the following:

```
sectionTitles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:sectionTitles.count];
sectionTitles = [NSMutableArray new];
sectionTitles = [NSMutableArray array];
sectionTitles = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:sectionTitles.count];
```

maybe some silly ones:

```
sectionTitles = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:@[]];
sectionTitles = [@[] mutableCopy];
```

There are lots of ways to create empty mutable arrays. Just read the [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/index.html).

Comment: I am amazed how often people (myself included) make empty arrays with anything more than the standard init - its like I want to keep my options open or something. Weird

Answer (score 25):

Passing non-null parameters is only partly the answer.

> The new Objective-C nullability annotations have huge benefits for code on the Swift side of the fence, but there's a substantial gain here even without writing a line of Swift. Pointers marked as `nonnull` will now give a hint during autocomplete and yield a warning if sent nil instead of a proper pointer.

Read NSHipster [comprehensive article](http://nshipster.com/swift-1.2/).

In oder to take advantage of the same contract in your own code, use `nonnull` or `nullable`:

**Obj-C**

```
- (nullable Photo *)photoForLocation:(nonnull Location *)location
```

Comment: That's is awesome, never knew this thing until now! So, nullable means value can be nil and nonnull means value shouldn't be null, right? +1

Answer (score -6):

Got the same error when initializing an NSMutableArray with zeros,

```
[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:0, 0, 0, 0, 0, nil];
```

Changed it to

```
[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:@[@0, @0, @0, @0, @0]];
```

Comment: A `NSMutableArray` is an array of object. Literals, like 0 or 1, are not objects. `@0` is a shorthand for `NSNumber` (an object) initialized with a value of 0.