# Error in AFNetworking following upgrade to Xcode 7

Tags: ios, afnetworking, xcode7

Following upgrading to Xcode 7 (7A21B) an AFNetworking error is thrown when building my current project in `AFURLSessionManager.m`. I've linked AFNetworking as a submodule in Git so it's regularly up to date.

The error is

> AFURLSessionManager.m:288:87: Null passed to a callee that requires a non-null argument

The line responsible:

```
        NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [[NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:nil] dataTaskWithURL:nil];
```

Obviously the nil arguments need to either be replaced with values or the method to instantiate the `dataTask` object needs to change but I'm not familiar enough with AFNetworking to make the change myself.

This is the entire method:

```
+ (void)initialize {
    if ([NSURLSessionTask class]) {
        NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [[NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:nil] dataTaskWithURL:nil];
        Class taskClass = [dataTask superclass];

        af_addMethod(taskClass, @selector(af_resume),  class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(af_resume)));
        af_addMethod(taskClass, @selector(af_suspend), class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(af_suspend)));
        af_swizzleSelector(taskClass, @selector(resume), @selector(af_resume));
        af_swizzleSelector(taskClass, @selector(suspend), @selector(af_suspend));

        [dataTask cancel];
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can quench this error?

Comment: This question should help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31088137/xcode-7-obj-c-null-passed-to-a-callee-that-requires-a-non-null-argument

Comment: Are you using the last AFNetworking release ? https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/releases/tag/2.6.0

Comment: @iAshish Yeah I saw that. Obviously I can instantiate the dataTask object somehow in a different way but I'm looking for a way of modifying this without introducing any side effects that I'm unaware of as I'm not familiar with AFNetworking.

Comment: @QuentinHayot Forgive my ignorance but is that not the version that Git would automatically pull down as a submodule? If not, how would I go about upgrading it?

Comment: You are right, I missed the part where you mentioned that, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a simple mistake. Thanks to Quentin for highlighting that the submodule in Git had not been updated. Doing this rectified the error.

Answer (score 0):

Tree solutions. Either use the shared session:

```
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:nil];
```

or decide on a configuration. Will you send files in background or only if your app is in foreground? Replace nil with either

```
[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]
```

or with

```
[NSURLSessionConfiguration  backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:@"My Identifier"]
```

or use NSURLSession directly instead of an obsolete third party framework.

Comment: The issue here is that in order to return an `NSURLSessionDataTask` object a URL is required and can't be nil. Both of the methods that return `NSURLSessionDataTask` are `dataTaskWithRequest:` and `dataTaskWithURL:` which obviously need non-null values.

Comment: Yap, but that is a problem of this 3rd party framework.Why you dont use NSURLSessions yourself?

Comment: Yeah, I normally do but the project I'm developing on is quite large with a lot of previous code that uses AFNetworking.