# Is it safe to assign NULL to an NSDate*?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsdate

I'm writing a game that includes a `Quest` class, which has a `completionDate` property of type `NSDate *`, which records the date and time that the player completed the quest. It's declaration (in Quest.h) is:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSDate *completionDate;
```

I figured it would be reasonable, in a case where the player had not yet completed a quest, to assign the quest's `completionDate` property a value of `NULL` to indicate this.  However, when I do:

```
quest.completionDate = NULL;
```

XCode (11.1) gives a warning on that line of code: `Null passed to a callee that requires a non-null argument`.

Despite the warning, my code seems to work as intended: Doing a check like the following to determine whether or not the quest has been completed seems to work fine:

```
if (quest.completionDate == NULL) { ... }
```

Researching this, I found similar questions like [Xcode 7, Obj-C, "Null passed to a callee that requires a non-null argument"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31088137/12484), with answers suggesting just using the `init` method to initialize an object to a default state. However, in the case of NSDate, [`init`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdate/1415407-init?language=objc) initializes the date to "now" (the current date/time), so that won't work for what I'm trying to do.

My question: Is there any reason not to assign `NULL` to an `NSDate *`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the nullable property attribute to your completionDate.

```
@property (nonatomic, nullable) NSDate *completionDate;
```

To learn more about declaring nullable types, see this Apple blog post [Nullability and Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=25).